# Show the composite function of a $C^1$ curve and a holomorphic function is piecewise $C^1$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Let $\gamma : [0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ is piecewise $C^1$ and $f $ is holomorphic on $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ is open.

> $\gamma $ is piecewise $C^1$ if there exists a partition on $[a,b]$ such that $\gamma$ is continuously differentiable on each interval.

Show that $f\circ \gamma :[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ is piecewise $C^1$ and $$(f\circ \gamma)^\prime (t)=f^\prime(\gamma (t))\gamma^\prime (t)$$

Here is what I've done: Let $(a_{k-1},a_k)$, where $k\in \{0,\dots , n\}$ be a partition of $[0,1]$ where $\gamma$ is $C^1$, and note $\gamma$ is a product of $n$ many curves defined on $(a_{k-1},a_k)$. WLOG, fix a $k$ and we have $\gamma_k$ as a curve from some point $z_0$ to $z_1$ in $U$ from the interval $(a_{k-1},a_k)$.
Define $g(t)=f^\prime(\gamma_k(t))\gamma_k^\prime(t)$ and $g$ is well defined on $(a_{k-1},a_k)$ for all k, because $\gamma$ is piecewise $C^1$ on $[0,1]$ and $f$ is complex differentiable on $\left|\gamma\right|= \{ \gamma(t): t \in [0,1] \}$.  I want to show it's differentiable so we can get continuity for free. Let $\epsilon >0$, and fix $t\in (a_{k-1},a_k)$, there exists some $\delta_1>0$ such that $$\left|\frac{(f\circ\gamma_k)(x)-(f\circ\gamma_k)(t)}{x-t}-g(t)\right|<\epsilon+\sup_{t\in (a_{k-1},a_k)}\left|f^\prime(\gamma(t))\right|\left|1+z_0-z_1\right|$$ whenever $\left|x-t\right|< \delta_1$. Note,  $(f\circ \gamma_k)(x)-(f\circ \gamma_k)(t)=f(\gamma_k(x))-f(\gamma_k(t))$. So we have
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(\gamma_k(x))-f(\gamma_k(t))}{x-t}-g(t)\right|&=\left|\frac{f(\gamma_k(x))-f(\gamma_k(t))}{x-t}-f^\prime(\gamma_k(t))+f^\prime(\gamma_k(t))-g(t)\right|
\newline &<\epsilon+\sup_{t\in (a_{k-1},a_k)}\left|f^\prime(\gamma_k(t))\right|\left|1+z_0-z_1\right|+\left|f^\prime(\gamma_k(t))\right|\left|1-\gamma_k^\prime(t)\right|
\newline &=\epsilon
\end{align}

I'm not sure whether the supreme of the prime exists on the curve, and I have $|1-\gamma_k^\prime(t)|=|1+z_1-z_0|$ just by differentiating $\gamma_k(t)=(a_{k}-t)z_0+(t-a_{k-1})z_1$, since $k$ is fixed.

By above we have $f\circ \gamma_k (t)$ is differentiable and equal to $g(t)$ for all $k$, and $\lim_{t \to a_k^-} (f\circ \gamma_k)^\prime(t)$ and $\lim_{t\to a_{k-1}^+}(f\circ \gamma_k)^\prime(t)$ exists since $\gamma_k$ is differentiable and $f$ is holomorphic on $U$. Hence we are done.

I am not sure whether or not my proof is close to a correct answer, can some one help me with this? THanks!

Comment: Offhand it looks to me that this is working too hard, but admittedly it depends what you can assume about holomorphic functions.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks for the comment! is it anywhere close to a right direction? Holomorphic on the text I use just means complex differentiable at each point.

Comment: I suggest breaking it down into two things. First show the theorem when $\gamma$ is from an arbitrary $[a,b] \to U$ (you must have the image of $\gamma$ contained in the domain of $f$ for this) and is $C^1$ everywhere. Then you apply that result to the pieces of your $\gamma$ here. Also, what does it require about differentiability at the endpoints? And check your text carefully: "holomorphic" generally requires complex diffentiability *on a neighborhood* of the point, not just at the point itself.